# Using fullcalendar "events as function" (in Vue) and returning a promise doesn't populate events when also updating resources?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm updating a resource list based on a changing select element by setting `this.calendarOptions.resources` and I'm also using a function to get events.

When I combine these things, the resources are displayed and the events seem to be fetched, but they are not displayed in the timeline.  I have also tried `calendarAPI.refetchEvents()` after updating the resources to see if that makes any difference.  The events are fetched, but are not displayed still.

If I fix the resources without updating it, the calendar events are displayed successfully.

Any thoughts why this might occur greatly appreciated.

```js
calendarOptions: {
    resources: [],
    events: this.getEvents
...
}
```

getEvents:

```js
async getEvents(info) {
    try {
        const response = await this.$http.get(myurl)
        return response.data.bookings
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

getResources:

```js
async getResources() {
    try {
        const response = await this.$http.get(myresourceurl)
        this.calendarOptions.resources = response.data.resources
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
111
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies.  Turns out the API for resources was returning "resourceId" instead of "id"